# How can change the selection style of points in paper.js?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

Can the segment-squares - on which a user clicks to modify a segment - be styled in paper.js?

Example [here](http://paperjs.org/examples/hit-testing/).

The current ones are too small.

I'm strongly considering to build a project on top of this library, but this could be a limitation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation for this is still missing, but right now you can adjust the size of these handles through `paper.settings.handleSize`, check here:

http://paperjs.org/reference/paperscope/#settings

There have been requests for more possibilities to change their appearance. What kind of styling are you thinking of?

Comment: One little remark. When i make the selection style of the point bigger, I can not click the whole square. I guess only the area of the initial square. This might be confusing for users.
[Example image here](http://imgur.com/a6npgQD) (For example the orange part in this image)

Comment: i think that's linked to the tolerance setting for hit tests, controlled by paper.settings.hitTolerance. But you're right, it should take the handle size into account.

Comment: The tolerance fixed it. Thanks. The library works really well. I'll post you the project once finished. :)